# Unable to search for ===

Tags: support, search, symbols

I had a question the differences between Javascript and PHP's handling of `==` vs `===` ([== vs === in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17474271/2200766)). I tried to be a good user and do a search but it looks like it errors or least returns no results when I try and search === (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3D%3D%3D). So unfortunately my question appears to be a duplicate (or is at least similar to) [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/2200766).

So in my opinion there is a bug in the code that doesn't allow me to search for ===

Comment: Google has the exact same "bug".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3D%3D%3D%22 - use quotes around code/operators.

Comment: @DannyBeckett so in terms of search engine lingo what is === trying to search for?